# How to create an interactive form in Joomla?

Tags: forms, joomla

I need to create an interactive form (to be used in Joomla) with some multiple options to choose from which gives the summary at the end when the user got to final question to choose from (for example to calculate the cost of shippment: first there is the basic price and then if someone wants fast delivery he picks up this field and extra charge is added to the total amount with information what has been added in that price). What is the best way or plugin/extension to be used in Joomla?

I tried to look for such solution with no results.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar using RSForms Pro by RSJoomla.  It is extremely powerful, but note it is a paid extension. https://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html